# MS EXCEL: Search and Extract Text from a String Using Wildcards in a Column Range

Tags: excel, substring, extract

Remove or Extract Dates from String - Using Wildcards in a Range Column

Using a MS Excel Array Formula, I would like a formula that will allow me to search within a string of text located in Cell A and extract only matching substring text that matches a unique wildcard pattern in Column Range: $D$2:$D$10.

OR any formula that will help me achieve either extract on the matching date from the string or remove matching date from the string using while using a column range.

COLUMN A (TEXT)

```
A2: Sally was employed from January 2016 - August 2018 and now works at home
A3: April 2013 through January 2014 was a good year
A4: Here are dates they worked for us 01/2011 til 09/2013
```

COLUMN C (OUTPUT RESULTS)

```
C2: Sally was employed from and now works at home
C3: was good
C4: Here's when they worked
```

COLUMN D (RANGE FIND WHAT)

```
D2: * 20?? through * 20??
D3:  ??/20?? til ??/20??
D4: * ???? - * ???? 
D5: * 2017 - Present
D6: * 20?? - * 20??
D7: * 20?? * 20??
```

[image]

Comment: Why are you SHOUTING? This is very annoying.

Comment: My apologies, thanks for the heads up... I retyped to be a little more subtle.

Comment: Can you please [edit you question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53400153/edit) and let us know what you have tried so far?

Comment: I've attempted several formulas

Comment: I've attempted several formulas: My use of the Index, Match and Search formula was able to find and return the corresponding value of the text pattern identified within the string. 
 =IFERROR(INDEX($D$2:$D$25,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$25,A2)),0))&"","")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a partial solution for you and I would love to know as well if it's possible to answer your question completely without using RegEx or a custom function.

Finding partial matches with wildcards, their relative positions in a list and where they start is really trivial and has been covered dozens of times on this website alone.

The one problem I cannot solve myself is removing the matched text with wildcards as obviously it can has differing lengths.  If the wildcards replace single characters only (?) it's quite simple and you should have no problems doing it yourself based on my formulas below.  Unfortunately I am at a loss how to solve the problem when * wildcards are used.

I don't know of a solution and would love to learn myself.

[image: ![enter image description here]

String found:

`=INDEX(list,MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(list,$A2)),-1,1)*(ROW(list)-ROW($A$7)+1)))`

Row found:

`=MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(list,A2)),-1,1)*ROW(list))`

Position found:

`=AGGREGATE(14, 6, SEARCH(list,A2), 1)`

Comment: Michal thank you, the provided formula does work, and will need a little tweaking but you're definitely on the right track, as to what I'm in need of. Again thank you