# Replicating the FIND tool in excel to search for text string, extract text from other string to search

Tags: excel

I have been using a combination of INDEX and FIND to return values based on the contents of the searched text string.

I noticed that using 'Find and Replace' I can search for 'ABC*Learning' in the cell 'For Kids: ABCs 123s Learning' and it will select the cell.

Is there a way I can have 'ABC*Learning' in a cell that the FIND function uses to search all the cells and return a specific value? I have included the code I have been working on as an example.

EX: Finds cell C6 and C7
***Using Find and Replace***
[image: Using Find and Replace]

I want to search cell B2 to find a match, then return C2.

***Field I am searching***
[image: Field I am searching]

As far as I know, once way to do it is to add a separate column, one for ABC and one for Learning, then search using that. But I have multiple different 'Alt ID' so going through each one and separating the values would be difficult. I would also have to redo my formula.

I believe that this post on Stackoverflow is similar but I am having trouble understanding the answer. I will be looking at it as I post this.

[MS EXCEL: Search and Extract Text from a String Using Wildcards in a Column Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53400153/ms-excel-search-and-extract-text-from-a-string-using-wildcards-in-a-column-rang)

Let me know if the code I have attached is useful. Sheet 1 is 'Learning' and Sheet 2 is 'brand'

Sheet 2 has '%%%' in all blank cells A5:C300

***Sheet 1***
[image: Sheet 1]

***Sheet 2***
[image: Sheet 2]

Cell D4 -

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(IFERROR(INDEX(Brand!$A$2:$A$300,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(Brand!$A$2:$A$300,C4)),-1,1)*(ROW(Brand!$A$2:$A$300)-ROW(Brand!$A$2)+1))),VLOOKUP(INDEX(Brand!$B$2:$B$300,MAX(IF(ISERROR(FIND(Brand!$B$2:$B$300,C4)),-1,1)*(ROW(Brand!$B$2:$B$300)-ROW(Brand!$B$2)+1))),Brand!$B$2:$C$300,2,FALSE))),"NonEdu")
```

Comment: I might end up using SEARCH instead, as that can natively use wildcards. Only problem would be that in my data BB and bb are two different terms, (Bubbly Bears) vs (berry bit). Right now I have my data searching MAX so every BB Bb and bb is returning Bubbly Bears. I will gladly take an answer for my question still so I will leave it open.